# Redis Lettuce java library notification on element expire

Tags: redis, lettuce

Can I manage redis notifications with Lettuce? I can't find any example or doc on it. I simply need to have some notification/callback in my java code when elements expire in Redis.

Let me put an example... I'm sorry, reading the Lettuce doc won't help me (and I I've taken some time)

Imagine I have a namespace of objects where I execute get and set commands:

```
"ONLINEUSERS:userid"
```

I add a user that will expire in an hour:

```
syncCommands.setex("ONLINEUSERS:"+userid,3600, mapper.writeValueAsString(userObject));
```

How can I have a method in my java code executed after those 3600 seconds make the key expire?

I mean... In the doc, the commands are:

```
StatefulRedisPubSubConnection<String, String> connection = client.connectPubSub()
connection.addListener(new RedisPubSubListener<String, String>() { ... })

RedisPubSubAsyncCommands<String, String> async = connection.async();
RedisFuture<Void> future = async.subscribe("channel");

// application flow continues
```

What would be the values for String, String array and  "channel" parameter matching my expire event for my key namespace?

Comment: Redis notifications (Keyspace notifications) use Pub/Sub, here's the documentation for Lettuce Pub/Sub: https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/wiki/Pub-Sub

Comment: Thanks. Some example for the parameters in the Lettuce async above will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @icordoba, I want to do the same, did you find more information? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue.

First, you need to make sure that your Redis server is configured to publish key-space event notifications. By default, this is disabled. Usually, the configuration file is located in `/etc/redis/redis.conf`. The property to look at is called `notify-keyspace-events`. If you want your Redis server to publish events for expired and deleted keys, you can pass a value such as `Ex` to the last property. Think to restart your Redis server once you applied a configuration change.

Second, you need to subscribe to the channel with name `__keyevent@0__:expired` from your Redis client instance.